# ударение в словах христианин и мусульманин

Tags: орфоэпия

почему в слове христианин ударение падает на последний слог, а в слове мусульманин на предпоследний? Как не ошибиться?

Answer (score 1):

Созвучие двух слов - **крестьянин** и **христианин**, близких и всё же разных по своим корням, определило необходимость иметь разницу в ударении. В других случаях (ж. род и мн. число) такого смещения ударения не произошло.

Comment: Как могло "созвучие определить ударение"?

Comment: Язык исключил созвучность, которая указывала на корневое родство.  Не было бы её, не было бы нужды в современной (и своевременной) коррекции ударения, подчёркивающей особенность этих слов.  См. Ответ с интересной историей: поз.3.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Comment: Оставьте комментарий

Answer (score 1):

Здесь интересная история.

1) Словарь приводит нам два варианта тематических суффиксов: ИН (ударный и безударный, осетИн, татАрин) и АНИН/ЯНИН - ударение на втором слоге (семья - семьянИн).

2) КрестьЯнин - от христианин, греческое заимствование (последователь Христа, потом православный, потом крестьянин). Ударение не изменялось.

3) Современный вариант "христианИн" - относительно новая норма,  у Аванесова (1987) ещё указывается: неправ! христиАнин.

Но прежнюю форму еще можно встретить у поэтов:

Но у бессмертия порога Он, верой пламенной горя, Как христиАнин, вспомнил Бога, Как верноподданный - царя (Апухтин).

Comment: Вера, "крестьянин" никакого отношения к "христианину" не имеет. Это древнейший ПИЕ  корень со значением "пахать".  Происходит **... कृषक (kṛṣaka) «крестьянин, пахарь» от कृशति (kṛśati) «пахать», корень कृष् (kṛṣ)**. (Вики) Если бы не это - плюсанул бы. )))

Comment: Кажется, вопрос о происхождении  "крестьянина" не решен однозначно, есть разные версии. Я ориентировалась на Шанского, У Черных , к сожалению, нет такой статьи. Генетическая связь русского слова «крестьяне» и санскритского «krsi» тоже пока что предположение. Вот слово «крестьяне» вроде бы фиксируется в письменных документах только с XIV века. А почему, как они раньше-то назывались? В тоже время в былинах про богатырей есть такое слово: "Не научился я такой премудрости - Орать-пахать да крестьянствовать".